# Translate Laravel function to SQL request to test

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, repository

I would like to test the output of Laravel function in MySQL, for this I need to translate the code to SQL request.

Function :

```
    return DB::table('products')
        ->leftJoin('product_locations', 'products.id', '=', 'product_locations.productId')
        ->select(DB::raw('IF(product_locations.id is not null,concat(product_locations.id,"-","M"),concat(products.id,"-","N")) as id'), DB::raw('IF(product_locations.id is not null,1,0) as multilocation'), 'products.productName', 'products.productName as text', 'product_locations.productLocationName', 'product_locations.binLocationName', 'product_locations.unitCost', 'product_locations.amount')
        ->orderBy('products.productName')
        ->distinct()
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use query logging:

```
DB::connection()->enableQueryLog();

DB::table('products')
        ->leftJoin('product_locations', 'products.id', '=', 'product_locations.productId')
        ->select(DB::raw('IF(product_locations.id is not null,concat(product_locations.id,"-","M"),concat(products.id,"-","N")) as id'), DB::raw('IF(product_locations.id is not null,1,0) as multilocation'), 'products.productName', 'products.productName as text', 'product_locations.productLocationName', 'product_locations.binLocationName', 'product_locations.unitCost', 'product_locations.amount')
        ->orderBy('products.productName')
        ->distinct()
        ->get();

dd(DB::getQueryLog())
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have tried to use query logging as you specified, but I can't see any result on the "chrom's developer tools"

Comment: This will display the executed queries on your screen, not in dev tools

Answer (score 0):

It is not the way, but still you can get the same result with less effort.

Make a small mistake in you query, for example use remove last character of a table name or a column name. Then it raise an error that shows the query. Then you can easily get your query on the screen.

In your query, use `product` instead of `products`. This will cause an error in query and display it.